# New cell for every word in cell - Excel

Tags: excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a column "poem" in which I wrote down one poem per cell. The poem consists of several words. I now want to make a new column " poem words" that lists all the words in the "poem" column in an extra cell (one word per cell). I want the data in this format to make a wordcloud with Tableau.

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

```
Poem Column
See how bright the wind is today

Poem Words Column
See
how
bright
the
wind
is 
today
```

Comment: `TEXTSPLIT()` will take an array of delimiters if need be to spill down words down a column. Possibly wrap in `UNIQUE()` to assert words are not repeating? Include sample data with expected results for more constructive help.

Comment: I tried TEXTSPLIT but it doesn't let me spill down the words in one column as shown in the added example. It wants to display the words cross-column.

Comment: leave the 2nd parameter blank and use the 3rd for the delimiter to split down rows.